# Any quick way to convert VS .net manual build into Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, migration

We are migrating 50+ .net project from TFS to GitHub, at the same, we want to use Jenkins to automate the build. Currently all the builds are done inside the Visual Studio manually. I know how to automate this build using MSBuild and we already have a lot of these projects building inside Jenkins.

My question: is there a way to set up these 50+ project quickly w/o creating them one by one manually? Anyway to script them? e.g. a Jenkins project has everything inside a folder, I can copy a sample project/folder to create a new one and modify something. Or create a Jenkins project using a script reading a config file? Any idea can save some time is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but too long for a comment so here it goes anyway. Following the [Joel test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) (which in no way is dogmatic for me but does make a *lot* of good points), and in my experience, you should already have an msbuild file now to build all those projects 'in one click'. Then, setting up a build server, in fact *any* build server, is just a matter of making it build that single parent project. This might not work for everyone, but for several projects I've worked on this had the following advantages:

- the entire build process gets defined by developpers, working locally on their machine, using 'standard' tools
- as such they don't need to spend hours in a web interface figuring out the appropriate build steps, dependencies and whatnot (also those hours would have been worthless in the end if switching to a different build server)
- since a complete build is now just a matter of `msbuild master.proj`, possibly along with some options to define configuration/platform/output directories getting this running on *any* build server should be painless and quick
- in the same manner this makes it easy to test different build servers with a minimum of time and migrate between them (also no need to ask SO questions on how to set everything up :)
- this also makes it easy for other developpers to get complete builds as well without having to go round via a build server

Anecdote: we once had Jenkins running on multiple different projects as well. It took us *days* to get everything running, with the templates etc, and we found the web intercae slow and cumbersome (and getting to know the API would have taken even more days). Then one day I got sick of this and made a bunch of msbuild scripts which could build *everything* from one msbuild command. That took much less time than setting up Jenkins, a couple of hours or so. Then I took a TeamCity installation we already had and made it build the new master project. Took like an hour and everything worked. Just recently I took the same project and got it working on Visual Studio Online, again in no time.

Comment: A bit away from the original topic, but I do think "build in one step" makes a lot sense and that's what we do with java all the time. From my understanding the .csproj and .sln file are acting as the build.xml in this case, wondering if there are ways to convert them into a proper build.xml?

Comment: Sorry, don't know exactly what you mean with 'build.xml', but yes if you have a .sln file which can build everything already then you can use that as 'master' project. For most projects I worked on this was not sufficient as we also needed to download some dependencies, build them, setup directory structure etc. So then we create an msbuild script to do all that.

Answer (score 0):

If those projects are more or less similar to build, you will probably be interested in using the template plug-in for jenkins. There you configure a dummy project such that it does what is common to (most of) the 50+ projects.

Afterwards you create a separate project for each: Create the first project and make it use the template project for each of the steps which can be shared with the template project (use build step from other project). All subsequent projects can be created as slightly adopted copy of this first 'real' project.

I use it such that the variable $JOB_NAME (the actual project name in jenkins that is) is part of the repository path and I can thus clone from http://example.org/$JOB_NAME/ 
Configured that way, I can include the source code management step in the templating job and use it unmodified. Similar with the build step and post-build step: they are run by a script which is somewhat universal accross all my projects (mostly calling make and guessing deployment / publication paths upon $JOB_NAME again).